# Trying to find range of values in another range and have output in another

Tags: excel, vba, find, named-ranges

Thought it would be as simple as, but somewhere i am wrong please help! So I am trying to find the values from rng1 in rng2 and have the output next to rng1

Thanks in advance

```
Sub FindValuestest()
Dim wb As Workbook, wks1, wks2 As Worksheet, rng1, rng2 As Range
Dim lRow1, lRow2 As Long
Dim v, n, r As Variant

On Error Resume Next


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wks1 = wb.Worksheets("FEPR")
Set wks2 = wb.Worksheets("EQUIP")
 
lRow1 = wks1.Cells(wks1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = wks2.Cells(wks2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng1 = wks1.Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
Set rng2 = wks2.Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

lRow1 = lRow1 - 1

For v = 1 To lRow1
    For n = 1 To lRow1
    If n = rng2.Find(n, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False) And rng2.Cells(n, 2) = "Commodity Tracking Bag Scanner" Then
    'Debug.Print n
    rng1.Cells(n, 2) = rng1.Cells(n) & " Scanner OK"
    End If
    Next
Next

For v = 1 To lRow1
    For n = 1 To lRow1
    If n = rng2.Find(n, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False) And rng2.Cells(, 2) = "Radio" Then
    rng1.Cells(n, 3) = rng1.Cells(n) & " Radio OK"
    End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: First step, get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`. That's hiding potential errors. Then, you don't ever use `v` so the two `For v = 1 To lRow1` loops seem useless. Then, `If n = rng2.Find(n, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)`... what exactly are you trying to do with that, in general terms?

Comment: So i am trying to find Names from sheet1 in sheet2 and see if those have checked out an item

Comment: Normally you only need one loop, and you would use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` or maybe `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`.

Comment: isn't Range.Find what i am doing? But the code right now just copies everything to another range but does not evaluate if the name also checked out an item... it's for a warehouse i want to know if Name A checked out a Scanner or not

Comment: `If n = rng2.Find(n, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)` is not how you check if the `Find` succeeded. You would do that with `Dim foundCell As Range`, `Set foundCell = rng2.Find(n....)`, `If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then`...`End If`. Though `n` is just a number and not the value of any actual cell... maybe you meant to use `rng1.Cells(n).Value`.

Answer (score 0):

### Match Values

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindValuestest()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("EQUIP")
    Dim sLast As Long: sLast = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1:A" & sLast)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("FEPR")
    Dim dLast As Long: dLast = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("B2:B" & dLast)
    
    ' Additional Variables
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Write
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To dLast
        cIndex = Application.Match(drg.Cells(i).Value, srg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            If srg.Cells(cIndex).Offset(, 1) _
                    = "Commodity Tracking Bag Scanner" Then
                drg.Cells(i).Offset(, 1).Value = drg.Cells(i) & " Scanner OK"
            ElseIf srg.Cells(cIndex).Offset(, 1) = "Radio" Then
                drg.Cells(i).Offset(, 2).Value = drg.Cells(i) & " Radio OK"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008 for your help, I split your code in two to get both results (a)the scanners that were checked out and (b) the radios... but only when i sort the source first from a>z for the scanner and z>a for the radios. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the data looks like. If you could share relevant screenshots of the worksheets or a link to your workbook, I could take a look and see what's wrong.

Comment: hey guys, just wanna say thanks again for all your help, with the sortation solution the Code works perfectly!